# Trying to add information from both loops in my xslt from my xml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert my xml to xslt table:

**Here is my xml:**

```
    .......

?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="VHSXSLT500.xsl"?>
<test> 
<VHSResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://SOMEURL.com/ABC">
    <BaseResponse>
        <VIN>123456789</VIN>
        <VehicleDamageabilityIndicator>AB</VehicleDamageabilityIndicator>
        <NumberOfTitlingTransactionsIndicator>AB</NumberOfTitlingTransactionsIndicator>
        <LastOwnerAcquisitionDate />
        <OrderDate>2020-08-12T10:54:00.579696-04:00</OrderDate>
        <ErrorReason>abc</ErrorReason>
    </BaseResponse>
</VHSResponse>
Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>System.NullReferenceException</ExceptionType>
</Error>
</test>
```

....
**This is xslt:*

......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<style>
h2 {text-align: center;}
</style>
<body>
  <h2>VHS TEST RESULTS</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>SrNo</th>
      <th>VIN</th>
      <th>VehicleDamageability Indicator</th>
      <th>Number Of Titling Transactions Indicator</th>
      <th>Last Owner Acquisition Date</th>
      <th>Order Date</th>
      <th>Error Reason</th>
      <th>500 Error Message</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//VHSResponse">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:number value="position()" format="1" /></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select=".//VIN"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select=".//VehicleDamageabilityIndicator"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select=".//NumberOfTitlingTransactionsIndicator"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select=".//LastOwnerAcquisitionDate"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select=".//OrderDate"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select=".//ErrorReason"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select=".//Message"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//Error">
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select=".//Message"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

.......

I am getting result but not what i want:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leMjO.png)

This is how i want results.. basically as entry in table in sequence to my xml's

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtuUD.png)

I know it needs some multiloop loop logic but no sure how to do that.. i am very very beginner to xslt

Also it does not populate results when i keep xlmns in xml, i can see table only if i remove xmlns from my xml.. not sure ahy please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per record, then -

1. If there is only one <Error> per record you do this:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="test">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:number value="position()" format="1" /></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/VIN"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/VehicleDamageabilityIndicator"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/NumberOfTitlingTransactionsIndicator"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/LastOwnerAcquisitionDate"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/OrderDate"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/ErrorReason"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="Error/Message"/></td>
    </tr>
```

2. If there is more than one error per message (which seems to be the case), you can do this:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="test">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:number value="position()" format="1" /></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/VIN"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/VehicleDamageabilityIndicator"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/NumberOfTitlingTransactionsIndicator"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/LastOwnerAcquisitionDate"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/OrderDate"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><xsl:value-of select="VHSResponse/BaseResponse/ErrorReason"/></td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <xsl:for-each select="Error">
          <xsl:value-of select="Message"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

This will result in all the Error messages being in one table cell - which is wht you want if you want one record per row.